# Making a button appear when three other buttons are clicked in Flash

Tags: flash

I have three movieclips: "countLettuce", "countCheese" and "countTomatoes". Each of these movieclips has two frames. When button1 is clicked countLettuce goes from frame 1 to 2; this is the same for countCheese and countTomatoes with button2 and button3, respectively. Now I want a new fourth button to appear when all three of my movieclips are at frame 2. How do I do this? Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [currentFrame](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#currentFrame) property and some maths, you can easily achieve your goal.

This is the one of possible solutions:

```
function updateButtonVisibleness(e:MouseEvent = null):void{
    var TOTAL_FRAMES:int = 2;
    forthButton.visible = (
                           (TOTAL_FRAMES-countLettuce.currentFrame) | 
                           (TOTAL_FRAMES-countCheese.currentFrame) |
                           (TOTAL_FRAMES-countTomatoes.currentFrame)
                          ) === 0;

}
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, updateButtonVisibleness);
button2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, updateButtonVisibleness);
button3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, updateButtonVisibleness);
```